# AsyncDisplayKit invalidateCalculatedSize Swift not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I have an `AsyncDisplayNode` from Facebook's AsyncDisplayKit framework. When there is a data change in my app, the content of that cell may need to be changed, and I want to signal that change by calling the `invalidateCalculatedSize` method, which should trigger a re-measurement for the next time the node is displayed.

However, Xcode displays the following error:

> ASDisplayNode does not have a member named 'invalidateCalculatedSize'

The same is true for all other types of nodes I tried, such as `ASCellNode`s and `ASTextCellNode`s, even though I see in the source code of ASTextCellNode a call to `invalidateCalculatedSize`.

On top of that, thinking that perhaps it's an Xcode Swift autocompletion issue, when I try to compile, the build fails with the same error as shown above. So, how *do* I invalidate the node size?

Comment: Oh, I think I found the answer here: https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit/issues/408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import a header file for sub-classing a node.

```
#import <AsyncDisplayKit/ASDisplayNode+Subclasses.h>
```